Apostrophe ' keeps show as &#39; on the email subject line with Ruby on rails 5.2 mailer
title contains Austen's books
The follow code snippets make the subject of the received email show as Austen&#39;s books
mail(from: from_email,
       to: to_email,
    subject: title.html_safe
 )

It looks like the html_safe method doesn't work for email subject but only for email body.
what other ruby method I can use to make apostrophe display as ' instead of &#39; on the received email subject line?

Where does title come from. What does title look like? How is title encoded?

Since you have &#39; instead of ' — most likely string contains &#39;rather than '
html_safe doesn't escape single quote
"'".html_safe
# => "'"

It also doesn't modify HTML-escaped quote
"&#39;".html_safe
# => "&#39;"

Looks like you need to unescape it
CGI.unescapeHTML("&#39;")
# => "'"


CGI.unescapeHTML(title) seemingly fixed the problem. Just weird that the title comes from database only has ' instead of &#39 stored; Anyway, problem solved. Thanks @mechnicov
